# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener

Please help. I'm not new to coding, but am new to java. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm using a book to learn java, and the following code is what I'm working on at the moment. I went to the books website and downloaded the source for this program and it gave me the same error message. Someone please help. I know this has been asked about, but I'm stuck and could really use some help.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TitleBar extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton b1;
    JButton b2;

    public TitleBar() {
        super("Title Bar");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLookAndFeel();
        b1 = new JButton("Rosencrantz");
        b2 = new JButton("Guildenstern");
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flow);
        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Object source = evt.getSource();
        if (source == b1) {
            setTitle("Rosencrantz");
        } else if (source == b2) {
            setTitle("Guildenstern");
        }
        repaint();
    }

    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
            );
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't use the system "
                + "look and feel: " + exc);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        TitleBar frame = new TitleBar();
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your error message

Comment: you need to learn basic of java,swing and awt.

Comment: your code doesn't give any errors

Comment: Works fine on my end, please share the full error message (stacktrace), it gives us hints where exactly the problem is. If you have additional code you may also share it, maybe the error is somewhere there.

Comment: Try to just implement the interface and then let the ide(eclipse) automatically  inherit the methods sometimes eclipse behave oddly. Or try to clean project this might work.

Comment: Have you by any chance defined any class named ActionEvent in your code?

Comment: the error message is: TitleBar.java:28: error: TitleBar is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener public class TitleBar extends JFrame implements ActionListener     i am using netBeans for my ide. could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your class works for me. Try this imports

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
```

Comment: his package declarations are fine

Answer (score 0):

i copied the code to my other pc and wouldnt you know, it worked fine. thanks for your help